# How to change DataGrid row color if record is changed

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I would like to achieve the follwing via binding if possible...

I have a WPF DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public bool Updated { get; set; }
}
```

My grids DataContext is is set to the observable collection.

What I would like to achieve...

- When the user changes a row in the datagrid the Updated field of the Product is changed to "true".
- As a result of this I can somehow bind the grid's row color to display a different colour which will indicate to the user that this row hasnt yet been saved.

I *think* that I will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to accomplish this but not certain on exactly how to do it. Additionally, is there a binding property on the grid to ensure that changes made on the UI update the backing store?

Cheers.

Comment: Yet more property abuse, use events if you have an event...

Comment: Ok, if I have 100 items in the grid, how can I "listen" to events raised by possibly any item. How to hook up a handler that can detect any change in the backing store?

Comment: Well, that is a problem, the exiting WPF functionality only supports properties well, if you want to keep your design clean and work with events you probably need to use other libraries like `Interactivity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801). Its [`EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger_members%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) is more flexible than the one in .NET.

Comment: @RemotecUk - can you use a collection derived from ObservableCollection - for example ObservableCollection<INotifypropertyChanged>?

Comment: why not bind to your Updated property and use a Converter  (IValueConverter) for it (make a template/style for your row) to decide which state your data have

Comment: Diregard my comment about events, i read your question sloppily, if `Updated` is in fact a persistent state rather than an event i would recommend to change its name to something more descriptive and that also sounds like a state

Answer (score 4):

1. Your `Product` class should [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so bindings to `Updated` are updated.

   You can additionally change the setters of all properties to set `Updated` to `true`.
2. You can trigger on the property:

   ```
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Updated}" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
   ```